# magento not sending any emails

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, configuration, email

Magento is not sending any emails, no confirmation mails, no invoice mails, no shipment mails or anything. I have configured all the settings in admin also. I am working on linux based shared hosting.

Comment: Try checking var/log/exception.log for error messages related to emails, if the folder/file doesn't exist you may need to enable logging on the Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Log Settings page.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/magento-e-mail-sending-does-not-work

Comment: there is no "log" folder in var :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sales email cron job not sending (1.9)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51891/sales-email-cron-job-not-sending-1-9)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a mail server configured an running on the server? You can try and check that by making a small PHP script. Here you can see how you can do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667208/how-to-check-if-a-mail-server-exists-or-not

```
$errno = 0;$errstr = '';
$fp = fsockopen("localhost", 25, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "No mail server responded on this server on port 25, validate your configuration";
}
```

Comment: yah mail server is configured. But its not sending any mails from magento admin

Comment: Ok, did you try to actually send a mail by a PHP script yet? Best way to debug these kinds of problems is step by step. Begin as close to the core as possible and verify everything is working ok. Then climb the ladder a step en recheck. So first thing to do now is to send an email with PHP. See the example on this page how to do that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if you ve set cronjob in cpanel , if so pl check it exists , Also check if the mail address you entered is valid.

Comment: this question is a year old, I am pretty sure that the email problem was resolved...

Answer (score -1):

if you have cron issue.I solve Email Problem by disable Queue of cron . 
Now Sent email directly instant avoid queue.
I think it is better for only low transactional magento store

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

CopyTo /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php Line:407(approximate)

```
/*if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
    ## @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue 
    $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
    $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
    $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
    'subject'           => $subject,
    'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
    'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
    'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
    'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
    'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
    'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
    ))
    ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
    ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
    $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

    return true;
}*/
```

You may flow this link if you have cron issue.
[Customer Order mail not sending](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74070/customer-order-mail-not-sending)

Comment: Overriding Core files is bad manner. You should extend the class in app/code/local rather.