# magento not sending email 1.9.1 of invoice

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I'm facing same problem as described here: [sales email cron job not sending (1.9)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51891/sales-email-cron-job-not-sending-1-9)

All emails are being sent, but when I create an invoice, Magento does not send an email.

I do see the emails in the `core_email_queue` and `core_email_queue_recipients` the `processed_at` times are all `NULL`

`cron.php` file shows blank when I hit it.

I'm seeing this in my logs:

> 2015-07-06T12:31:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/.../public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 7703

I need help, please help

Comment: 2015-07-06T12:31:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /home/edgynailsupply/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 7703

Comment: Im getting this warning in logs