# Customer Order mail not sending

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, order-email, ce-1.9.1.1

Customer not get any mail for Order success . But get new user registration mail on Magento-1.9.1.1

I already set Store email as

```
01. System ==> configuration ==> Store Email Addresses All as:
    support@mydomain.com   
02. System ==> configuration ==>Sales==> Sales Emails==>
    Order:Enable (All configured properly)
03. System ==> configuration ==>ADVANCED==>System ==> 
    Mail Sending Settings:
    a) Disable Email Communications: NO
    b)Host: mail.mydomain.com Port:25
```

Admin Panel:

```
a). Sales==>Order==>Open Order ==>Invoice 
Show here Order # 100000080 (the order confirmation email is not sent)
```

Comment: Please check for errors in the email html templates (malformed html) or any of the included blocks. Also check error logs and apache mail log for issues

Comment: Use  New Order (Default Template from Locale), no edit code

Comment: Template code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6c5g1abkztc8j9v/order_new.html?dl=0

Comment: Check this http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1&ei=ctgBdtCY&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=439&ts=1436696773&sig=AKQ9UO8_YTTJGOcfa7KdzeE3_42ESoR3uw

Comment: Check if cron is setup correctly.

Comment: I don't configure cron yet, but new user email send successfully

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the Magento cronjob is correctly set up. Magento 1.9 sends the order confirmation mails in a queue which is processed by the cron. I strongly advise to use [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to check if the cron is running correctly. Even if you are sure that it runs on the server-side, there may be issues with the cronjob on Magento side. See e.g. [this problem and solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10931/142).

Comment: Why I Use 3rd Party module? Order notification mail common feature for any ecom CMS

Comment: @matinict The 3rd party module is only for checking if the cron is set up correctly. If your order confirmation mails are not sent, something is wrong with your cron.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have edited the template of the new order email in

```
System -> Transactional Emails
```

can be that is corrupted.
Also and check which template you are using in

```
System -> Configuration -> Sale Emails
```

Comment: i already check my  Transactional/Sale Emails from web mail login & add template https://www.dropbox.com/s/6c5g1abkztc8j9v/order_new.html?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I solve Email Problem by disable Queue of cron . 
Now Sent email directly instant avoid queue.
I think it is better for only low transactional magento store

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php Line:407(approximate) 

/*if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
    ## @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue 
    $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
    $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
    $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
    'subject'           => $subject,
    'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
    'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
    'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
    'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
    'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
    'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
    ))
    ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
    ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
    $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

    return true;
}*/
```